# Question about Surjectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

everyone. I'm preparing for a first abstract algebra exam and have this question about surjectivity.

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ by $f(x)=|x|$. Since this is a mapping from the integers to the natural numbers (text considers natural numbers to be $\mathbb{N}$={$0,1,2,...$}), if I choose $b\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $f(x)=b$ to be $|b|$ then $f(|b|)=||b||=|b|=b$, so all natural numbers have a corresponding pre-image in the integers. Is this correct?

Comment: Why not just observe that $f(b) = b$ for any $b \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: You do have the right idea, though I wouldnt use the abs value symbol in the arguement of the function. You should always try to make it as arbitrary as possible, if that makes sense.

Comment: well, in a purely abstract way I would mention that you use this to show that the inclusion $\mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a rightinverse and so it has to be surjective (a priori $\mathbb{N}$ and  $\mathbb{Z}$ could and in my opinion should be regarded as seperate sets and not necessarily subsets of each other)